# The @edit Route is not working... showing 404 not found

Tags: laravel

the @edit route is not creating. everything is ok but showing 404 not found
the problem is on the last route. I ran the php artisan route:list code but not showing any route named /profile/{user}/edit
the web.php code ->>>>>

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();



Route::get('/p/{post}','App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@show');

Route::get('/p/create','App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create');

Route::post('/p','App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@store');

Route::get('/profile/{user}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'index'])->name('profile.show');

Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit','ProfilesController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
```

---

the profiles controller code ->>>>>

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{

    public function edit(User $user)

    {
            return view('profiles.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function index(User $user)

    {
        return view('profiles.index', compact('user'));
    }

    
}
```

---

the index.blade.php code --->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div><h1>here is a big design</h1></div>
    <br>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-baseline">
        <h1>{{ $user->username}}</h1>
        <a href="/p/create">Add New Post</a>
    </div>
    
    <a href="/profile/{{ $user->id }}/edit">Edit Profile</a>
    
    <div class="pr-5"><strong>{{$user->posts->count()}}</strong> posts</div>
    <div class="pr-5"><strong></strong> followers</div>
    <div class="pr-5"><strong></strong> following</div>
    <br>
    <div><h1>{{ $user->profile->title}}</h1></div>
    <br>
    <div><h1>{{ $user->profile->description}}</h1></div>
    <br>
    <div><h1>{{ $user->profile->url ?? 'N/A'}}</h1></div>
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row pt-5">
        @foreach($user->posts as $post)
            <div class="col-4 pb-4">
                <a href="/p/{{$post->id}}">
                    <img src="/storage/{{$post->image}}" class="w-100">
                </a>
            </div>

        @endforeach
    </div>

</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using, as the way to define routes changed as of L8.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you cache your routes?

Comment: I am using laravel 8.35.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your route to

```
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit',[ProfilesController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
```

Your way `'ProfilesController@edit'` doesn't take `use App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController;` into account.

---

Offtopic suggestion: since you already named your routes I suggest you use the named routes in your blade files instead of hardcoding them:

```
<a href="{{ route('profile.edit', $user) }}">Edit Profile</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="/profile/{{ $user->id }}/edit">Edit Profile</a>
```

This way, should you decide to change a URL some time later, you only need to change it in your `web.php` file *once*, not all of your hardcoded occurences

Comment: Route [profile.edit] not defined.............. laravel is showing this now

Comment: It is working now after caching the routes